# how to declare an array based on if else condition inside a function and calling this array

Tags: c

Hi I am declaring an array based on condition in a function when I am calling this function I am getting below error

```
 main.c:24:17: error: ‘rsi’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         rsii[i]=rsi[i];
```

This is my code:

```c
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h> 
    void   RootSequenceIndex( int RSIIndex, uint32_t rsii[4])
    {
        //uint32_t rsi[839];
        if (RSIIndex==0)
        {
            uint32_t rsi[4] = {1,2,3,4};
        }
        else if(RSIIndex==1)
        {
            uint32_t rsi[4] = {5,6,7,8};
        }
        else if(RSIIndex==2)
        {
            uint32_t rsi[4] = {9,10,11,12};
        }
        else
        {
            uint32_t rsi[4] = {13,14,15,16};
        }
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            rsii[i]=rsi[i];
        }
        
    }
    int main()
    {
        int RSIIndex=0;
        uint32_t rssi[4] ;
        RootSequenceIndex( RSIIndex,rssi);
        for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
          printf( "%d\n", rssi[i]);
        }
        //return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There are a few flaws in your wording: You do not get an error when you call this function. You cannot compile your code and hence no calling. Also from your title: You can never call an array. You can only access it.

Comment: The braces limit the scope of each array.  You can't do it like that.  You'd have to call the array copy code in each statement block.

Comment: You cannot access a variable that was defined in another scope. Define your array above your `if else` cascade and only assign the values in the branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already written in other answers you have to declare `rsi` at function scope instead of in `if` blocks.

To avoid assigning array elements in a loop you can use a pointer `rsi` instead of an array and assign a constant array to it.

```
void   RootSequenceIndex( int RSIIndex, uint32_t rsii[4])
{
    const uint32_t *rsi;
    
    if (RSIIndex==0)
    {
        rsi = (const uint32_t[4]){1,2,3,4};
    }
    else if(RSIIndex==1)
    {
        rsi = (const uint32_t[4]){5,6,7,8};
    }
    else if(RSIIndex==2)
    {
        rsi = (const uint32_t[4]){9,10,11,12};
    }
    else
    {
        rsi = (const uint32_t[4]){13,14,15,16};
    }
    
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        rsii[i]=rsi[i];
    }
    
}
```

**Note:** I consider the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66119315/10622916) with a two-dimensional array better than this one.

Answer (score 4):

Your array definitions are only visible inside the block where they are defined. You seem to try this because you can only provide initialization values when you define a variable.

To avoid that problem, you could try this:

```c
#define RSI_ELEMENTS 4

void   RootSequenceIndex( int RSIIndex, uint32_t rsii[RSI_ELEMENTS])
{
    static const uint32_t rsi[][RSI_ELEMENTS] = {{1,2,3,4},
                                                 {5,6,7,8},
                                                 {9,10,11,12},
                                                 {13,14,15,16}};

    size_t MaxIndex = sizeof(rsi)/sizeof(rsi[0]);
    if (RSIIndex > MaxIndex - 1 || RSIIndex < 0)
       RSIIndex = MaxIndex - 1 ;

    size_t MaxElement = sizeof(rsi[0])/sizeof(rsi[0][0]);
    for (int i=0; i < MaxElement; i++)
    {
        rsii[i]=rsi[RSIIndex][i];
    }        
}
```

Comment: Also seems like a good idea to use sizeof to generate the default RSIIIndex and set the bound on i rather than hardcoding the 3 and 4

Comment: actually in my main code, the array size is rsi[839][839].. so it 839x839 with each entry is in hex like 0x045d85910.. is 839x839 not huge? this is the reason i split based on if condition...

Comment: Maybe that is huge, but the needed memory doesn't get smaller if you split in smaller pieces.

Comment: Do you mean `rsi` is `rsi[839]` and Index is in range 0..838 or is `rsi[839][839]` and Index is on top?

Comment: actual table size is 839x839.. total indices are 839 and for each index the length of the vector is 839

Comment: You can also extend my snippet to hold 839x839 values.

Comment: is Bodo answer saves some memory because he is assigning array inside if conditions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228468/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-python-spark).

Answer (score 1):

The array you declare only exists within the scope it is declared, i.e. within each `if` block, so it is not accessible outside of that.

You would need to declare the array outside the `if` block, then assign values to it inside:

```
void   RootSequenceIndex( int RSIIndex, uint32_t rsii[4])
{
    uint32_t rsi[4];
    if (RSIIndex==0)
    {
        rsi[0] = 1;
        rsi[1] = 2;
        rsi[2] = 3;
        rsi[3] = 4;
    }
    else if(RSIIndex==1)
    {
        rsi[0] = 5;
        rsi[1] = 6;
        rsi[2] = 7;
        rsi[3] = 8;
    }
    else if(RSIIndex==2)
    {
        rsi[0] = 9;
        rsi[1] = 10;
        rsi[2] = 11;
        rsi[3] = 12;
    }
    else
    {
        rsi[0] = 13;
        rsi[1] = 14;
        rsi[2] = 15;
        rsi[3] = 16;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        rsii[i]=rsi[i];
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can get rid of the array altogether and use another loop to generate the values that would be in it.

```
void   RootSequenceIndex( int RSIIndex, uint32_t rsii[4])
{
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        rsii[i] = RSIIndex * 4 + 1 + i;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Semi-advanced topic, but please note that "smart" solutions like `RSIIndex * 4 + 1 + i` run-time calculation are always much slower than table look-ups. Such code is only  good if you wish to reduce read-only memory use.